# Facebook Page Webhook stopped working. It was working from last 1 year

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

We have configured webhook in facebook app earliear.
After subscribing the facebook page we were able to receive real time update on our server from facebook page.
Now webhook was stopped working.
We are not getting any real time update for new post from facebook page.

We have pre-configured setup as per bellow guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime/

I'm able to view that my page has installed my app by using bellow sample api:
GET graph.facebook.com/PageID/subscribed_apps

But not getting real time update

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the webhook, and then add it again. (This helps in most such cases. Facebook will stop sending updates if your endpoint is too slow to respond or responds with errors over a certain period of time.)

Comment: Thanks for response @CBroe.

Comment: I have tried removing and adding new but there is no endpoint call. Our endpoint URL is active but not called by webhook.

Comment: Then check if the page is still correctly subscribed for updates.

Comment: Yes, Page is subscribed.
One thing to add,My facebook app is not live but it has been working from last year. Can this issue be due to bellow notification after new security changes of fb:

"Applications will only be able to receive test webhooks sent from the app dashboard while they are in development. No production data, including that of app admins, developers, and testers, will be delivered unless the app is live."

Comment: Well yeah, if you want updates from a “live” page (as opposed to one created by a test user), you need to set your app live now as well.

Comment: Yes. After making live its started working . But I'm sure earlier it was working for Faacebook page admin user in development mode of app too.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, earlier apps in dev mode were unrestricted, but with the current changes in light of Cambridge Analytica, they changed that.

Comment: Perfect. I'm unable to mark your above answer best and resolved it. But no option. Pls let me know how can mark solved

Comment: Well that requires that someone adds an answer first ;-) - so far we have only been discussing in comments here. I’ve added an answer for you now with the main points from my comments.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Got it. @Lightness Races in Orbit
Now CBroe answered it instead of comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if a webhook stops working: For Remove the webhook, and then add it again. (This helps in most such cases. Facebook will stop sending updates if your endpoint is too slow to respond or responds with errors over a certain period of time.)

> One thing to add,My facebook app is not live but it has been working from last year.

If you want updates from a “live” page (as opposed to one created by a test user), you need to set your app live now as well.

---

Previously apps in dev mode were mostly unrestricted, but with the current changes in light of Cambridge Analytica, they changed that.

Comment: Fine. I had to make previous development mode app live after adding privacy policy doc url then webhook started working. Thanks @CBroe for nice discussion.